# How to Use the Bid Simulator in Adwords API v201003

Tags: java, google-ads-api

In the latest version of the Adwords API, [Google announced](http://adwordsapi.blogspot.com/2010/05/introducing-adwords-api-version-v201003.html) the availability of the Bid Simulator (i.e. the ability to get estimated clicks, cost, and ad position).

However, I can't find any example code for this.  Can anyone provide an example of how to lookup clicks, cost, and ad position given a keyword, match type, and max cpc using the Adwords v201003 API in Java?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell I think you mean the [BidLandscapeService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/v2009/docs/reference/BidLandscapeService.html)? For Java at least, if you download the [beta Java client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/downloads/detail?name=adwords-api-8.1.0.tar.gz&can=2&q=), there's an example, '[GetCriterionBidLandscape.java](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-adwords-java/source/browse/trunk/examples/v201003/GetCriterionBidLandscape.java)' which retrieves existing specified bid landscapes, from which the Set operations should be fairly straightfowrard. The 201003 release is still beta so I imagine that a corresponding Set example is still in the works.

Comment: Thanks very much for this response...  Now my problem is that the service won't return anything...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277318/adwords-api-bidlandscapeservice-never-returns-anything

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for the [BidLandscapeService](http://code.google.com/apis/adwords/docs/reference/latest/BidLandscapeService.html). You feed in an AdGroup and get back a collection of LandscapePoints. Each of those points has the estimated clicks and cost.